# Loop over List R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am using a function I found on a Duke Sports Analytics site to scrape college basketball games from sportsreference.com. It takes a url as an argument. The code below scrapes all games for Duke from 2011-2022. I have a list of multiple teams (Duke, Baylor, Kansas, Gonzaga). I need to substitute "duke" within the url being concatenated with the 4 team names I listed. How could I alter this code to loop through all those teams, and not just Duke which is hardcoded into the code?

```
teams <- as.list(c("Gonzaga", "Baylor", "Kansas", "Duke"))

game_logs <- tibble(
   season_url = 2011:2022,
  season = paste0(season_url - 1, "-", str_sub(season_url, start = 3)),
  url = paste0("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/duke/", season_url, "- 
schedule.html")
) %>%
  mutate(data = map(url, possibly(scrape_game_logs, otherwise = NA)))
```

Comment: why not use `sprintf("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/%s-schedule.html", season_url)`

Comment: @akun did not work for me

Comment: sorry not clear I meant to change the `url = paste0(..` step with that sprintf.

Comment: @akrun I tried that, but no luck. Can you explain why sprintf should work in place of paste0?

Comment: YOu can use `paste0` as well.  It is just that `sprintf` is more dynamic if we want to insert multiple elements.  IN the `paste0`, I find you are using `/duke/`  why not remove the `duke/` part from the initial link and then paste

Comment: When you say that did not work, it is difficult to understand as your example is not reproducible i.e. `scrape_game_logs` is not showed

Comment: @akrun Got it. But in your line of code, where is it specified that it should be looping through duke, baylor, gonzaga, etc?

Comment: It is the `%s` where it is interpolated.  Okay.  I think I missed the `teams` part i..e `sprintf("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/%s/%s-schedule.html", teams, season_url)`

Comment: @akrun With that we are very close. Only issue is that it is grabbing the 2011 games for Gonzaga, 2012 games for Baylor, 2013 for Kansas, etc. Ideally it would grab 2011-2022 for all 4 teams. If you can't help with that, no worries.

Comment: I guess you need to have a `crossing` with `teams` first i.e. `teams <- (c("Gonzaga", "Baylor", "Kansas", "Duke"));crossing(teams, season_url = 2011:2022)%>%...` this makes sure you haveall combinations

Comment: @akrun Can you post where crossing should be used within an answer? Makes sense but am slightly confused

Comment: I posted a solution to create the data including all the steps except the last one with `map` as ithe function is not showed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to create combinations with `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
teams <- c("Gonzaga", "Baylor", "Kansas", "Duke")
df1 <- crossing(season_url = 2011:2022, teams) %>%
     mutate(season = str_c(season_url - 1, "-", str_sub(season_url, start = 3)),
   url = glue::glue("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/",
            "{teams}/{season_url}-schedule.html"))
```

-output

```
> df1
# A tibble: 48 × 4
   season_url teams   season  url                                                                    
        <int> <chr>   <chr>   <glue>                                                                 
 1       2011 Baylor  2010-11 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Baylor/2011-schedule.html 
 2       2011 Duke    2010-11 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Duke/2011-schedule.html   
 3       2011 Gonzaga 2010-11 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Gonzaga/2011-schedule.html
 4       2011 Kansas  2010-11 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Kansas/2011-schedule.html 
 5       2012 Baylor  2011-12 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Baylor/2012-schedule.html 
 6       2012 Duke    2011-12 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Duke/2012-schedule.html   
 7       2012 Gonzaga 2011-12 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Gonzaga/2012-schedule.html
 8       2012 Kansas  2011-12 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Kansas/2012-schedule.html 
 9       2013 Baylor  2012-13 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Baylor/2013-schedule.html 
10       2013 Duke    2012-13 https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/Duke/2013-schedule.html   
# … with 38 more rows
```